# VS2005 How to Search for breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2005

How can I search for breakpoints in VS2005 or go to next breakpoint?

I need this feature when I add a bunch of breakpoints to unfamiliar code, say on all bits of dodgy code connected with some some feature and I want to make sure I have broken on all of them.  Kind of limited code coverage test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click

> Debug->Windows->Breakpoints.

This gives you a list of all break points, and you can select the columns to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

**Ctrl-Alt-B** displays the Breakpoints dialog box.